# Casting Any to AnyObject in Swift

Tags: swift

I have an object contained within a Dictionary like so:

```
let dict:<String, Any> = ["obj": self]
```

Then later on I am trying to use that object as the target of a button press:

```
button.addTarget(dict["obj"], action: "buttonPress:", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
```

And I get the error:

```
Type '(String, Any)' does not conform to protocol 'AnyObject'
```

I am guessing here my issue is trying to cast `Any` as `AnyObject`. Is this even possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No downcasting from `Any` to `AnyObject` is not possible, and yes, the problem you have is about `Any` not convertible to `AnyObject`.

`Any` can represent any type (classes, structs, enums, ints, strings etc.), whereas `AnyObject` can represent reference types only (i.e. classes).

To solve the problem, I think you should change your dictionary to store values of `AnyObject` type:

```
let dict:<String, AnyObject> = ["obj": self]
```

Note that even if the dictionary contains `AnyObject` values, it can also store:

- numbers
- strings
- arrays
- dictionaries

because these types are automatically bridged to the corresponding objc types (`NSNumber`, `NSArray`, `NSDictionary`, etc.)

If you really need to have max flexibility, then I suggest using `NSDictionary` - but in that case value types must be explicitly boxed in reference types (i.e. `int` in `NSNumber`, etc.).

Also @rintaro's answer in another good option.

Answer (score 3):

`Any` to `AnyObject` is possible. You can unwrap `Any` to `AnyObject` by using `.unsafelyUnwrapped` of `Any` regardless it's classes, structs, enums, ints, strings etc.

Here `_change[.oldKey]` returns `Any`, unwrap and cast it to `AnyObject` as done in below code.

```
 override public func observeValue(forKeyPath keyPath: String?, of object: Any?, change: [NSKeyValueChangeKey : Any]?, context: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?) {

        guard let oldKey = (_change[.oldKey].unsafelyUnwrapped as AnyObject).cgPointValue else {
                        return
                    }
        guard let newKey = (_change[.newKey].unsafelyUnwrapped as AnyObject).cgPointValue else {
                        return
                    }
        print(oldKey)
        print(newKey)
    }  
extension NSKeyValueChangeKey {
    public static let newKey: NSKeyValueChangeKey
    public static let oldKey: NSKeyValueChangeKey
}
```

I've used KVO `ObserveValue forKeyPath` to receive change in `[NSKeyValueChangeKey : Any]` format.
I successfully retrieved `CGPoint` values converted from `Any` to `AnyObject` then to `CGPoint`.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot cast `Any` to `AnyObject`, but you **can** cast it to any concrete class:

```
    button.addTarget(dict["obj"] as UIViewController, action: "buttonPress:", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
```

Of course this may causes runtime error if `dict["obj"]` is not `UIViewController`, so make it safer:

```
    if let target = dict["obj"] as? UIViewController {
        button.addTarget(target, action: "buttonPress:", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
    }
    else {
        fatalError("dict[\"obj\"] is not UIViewController!")
    }
```

And of course, it's better to use your own subclass, instead of `UIViewController`.

Comment: In both cases, if dict["obj"] is the wrong type, the code is broken. In the first case, the system will tell you exactly where the problem is, in the second case, the code will run and you will be left wondering why your button doesn't work. For that reason, I think the first code is safer.

Comment: Oh, I see, and agree with that in this case.

Comment: Now both blocks of code effectively do the same thing. Why go with the second, more complex, block of code rather than the first, much simpler one? I still think the first block of code is the better choice. (I like your answer best, but the first block better than the second.)